# Using recursive function to count occurences of letters

Tags: c, function, recursion, variable-assignment

i was asked to prepare an assignment using recursive function but this kind of function is hard for me to understand. Could you please help me? Program has to count the occurences of specifed letters in source string.

Comment: People will be more eager to help you if you provide some code in which you tried and failed. Just a tip for future.

Comment: Actually i have nothing to work on. Just a name of function I have to implement.  int recCounter(char * source, int letter). I know how to do the task using iterative function but recursive one is too difficult.

Comment: We are not a homework service. You should consult a good book or tutorial to get the concept this way you won't learn it ever.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...
EDIT: You added more info, so code has changed a bit

```
int recCounter(char * source, int letter) {
    if(*source == '\0')
        return 0;

    if(source[0] == letter) {
        *source++;
        return 1 + recCounter(source, letter);
    }

    *source++;
    return 0 + recCounter(source, letter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i will study this code as soon as i get home. Really appreciate it.